# Insert Data into Table if a condition is true

Tags: sql

### SQL statement Question

I have an instance where I need to insert one record multiple times in a DB table that contains a unique reference column. I'm declaring a variable and using a select statement to populate variable and then running an insert statement. The issue is that when grabbing unique value into variable it only grabs the last record in the reference table. I need for insert statement to insert at each point where a record is found.

```
DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @RuleID INT;

SELECT @RuleID = RuleID from Rules where Rule_Name = 'VERSION_ID' and Field = 'TSH'
SELECT @ID = ID FROM CHANNELS WHERE SUBSTRING(CHANNEL_NAME,0,4) != 'HEL'

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Rule_Items
VALUES(@ID,@RuleID,0,'2.5.1','E','A',0,getdate())
END
```

Comment: Please add table definitions, sample data and the desired output to your question. That would help people understand why you say Gordon's query is not giving you the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all combinations, you can use `insert . . . select` with a `cross join`:

```
INSERT INTO Rule_Items
    select c.id, r.ruleid, 0, '2.5.1', 'E', 'A', 0, getdate()
    from rules r cross join
         channels c
    where r.Rule_Name = 'VERSION_ID' and r.Field = 'TSH' and
          SUBSTRING(c.CHANNEL_NAME, 0, 4) <> 'HEL';
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I get the same issue as with my query, the select statement will only get the last record and insert that and not all records.

Comment: @user3498953 . . . That doesn't make sense.  This does a `cross join` so it should be inserting all combinations of matching records from the two tables.  Your query only inserted one row.

Comment: Sorry it took awhile to get back, yes it only inserted one row. After some review on the web and debugging when SQL Server is running through the select statement it will overwrite each time and when it it gets to the end of the matching records it will always insert the last. I found a solution by using a cursor. I will post my answer of what was done.

Comment: @user3498953 . . . That makes no sense.  All the records from the `select` query will be inserted.  If it only produces one record, then only one would be inserted.  But there is no "overwriting" on an `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a cursor and create a temp table. Here is query that worked.

```
**--BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @Channelid INT
DECLARE @RuleID INT
SELECT  @RuleID = RuleID From Rules Where Rule_Name = 'VERSION_ID'

DECLARE GetChannelId CURSOR FOR SELECT Channelid FROM HL7_Channels WHERE Channel_Name not like 'MU2%' AND Channel_Description LIKE '%outbound%'
OPEN GetChannelId
FETCH GetChannelId INTO @Channelid
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
      BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 From Rule_Items Where ChannelId = @Channelid AND RuleID = @RuleID)
            BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO Rule_Items VALUES (@Channelid,@RuleID,0,'2.5.1','E','A',0,getdate())
            END         
FETCH GetChannelId INTO @Channelid
CONTINUE 
      END
CLOSE GetChannelId
DEALLOCATE GetChannelId

--ROLLBACK TRAN
--COMMIT TRAN**
```